Find the shaded area in figure two lines
Find the area of the shaded region:

The limitation I am able to find from the figure: $\left[-2, 0\right]$ and $\left[0, 1\right]$.
Integrals:
$$\int_{-2}^{0} (x + 2) \, dx + \int_{0}^{1} (2e^{-x}) \, dx$$
$= \left[\frac{x^2}{2} + 2x\right]_{-2}^{0} + \left[ -2e^{-x}\right]_{0}^{1}$
Applying:
$= (\left(\frac{\color{blue}{0}^2}{2} + 2(\color{blue}{0})\right) - \left(\frac{(\color{blue}{-2})^2}{2} + 2(\color{blue}{-2})\right)) + (\left(-2e^{-(\color{red}{1})}\right) - \left(-2e^{-(\color{red}{0})}\right))$
My Solution:
$$0 + 2 -2e^{-1} + 2$$
$$4-2e^{-1}$$
... = weird decimal numbers.
My answer was wrong, according to the back of the book the correct solution is: $$(\color{red}{4-2e^{-1}}) \approx 3.3$$

Your answer is correct. Check your arithmetic again?

Your answer is not wrong, just simplify it

Your answer matches the book, but if you show in more detail what happened when you tried comparing them we can explain what went wrong there. (Maybe you had a sign error.) What do you think your answer is in the form $a+b/e$? What is that to 1 decimal place?

Does your teacher require you to use calculus for the part to the left of the $x$ axis?

Since $2e^{0}=2$ you get
$\left(\frac{{0}^2}{2} + 2({0})\right) - \left(\frac{({-2})^2}{2} + 2({-2})\right)+ \left(-2e^{-{1}}\right) - (-2) = 0 + 2 - 2e^{-1}+2 = 4 - 2e^{-1}
 $

Yes, was confused  but, thanks a lot.

No worries :) sometimes you just need to go on
